# Is there a sqlite function that checks if cell value exists

Tags: python, sqlite

I'm working on this simple table that's made up of 3 columns

- `ID` which is just a serial number for all rows (`PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL`)
- `PCode` which has the code given to the product (`INTEGER`)
- `PName` which has the product's name (`TEXT`)

I want to create a tkinter window that lets the user add new products (Codes and names) into this table. But it first needs to check if that product code or name already exist, if the product name exists, Show window error, if product code exists, give it the name assigned to it by the user. If product code and name don't already exist, insert a new row that has them.
How do I make sqlite check if the text or integer already exists ? Thank you.

Comment: uses SQL query `SELECT` to select this element - if you get zero results then it doesn't exist in database. ie. something similar to `SELECT ... FROM ... WHERE PCode = ... OR PName = ... `

Comment: I want the program to do it automatically. My problem is, how can the program automatically check if the qurey results in nothing. That's what I'm asking about

Comment: you can't do it automatically - you have to write some SQL query to do it. And I don't know if SQLite has something like `INSERT OR UPDATE` but it still would need to write this query.

Comment: Actually, you can, I got an idea I'll write in the answers

Comment: BTW: `results = execute("SELECT ...")` and check `if results:` or `if len(results) > 0:`

Comment: Exactly what I was gonna do :D Please write it as an answer so I can approve it. Thank you.

Comment: BTW it your idea resolves your problem then write as answer but if this is only idea but it still not solution then put it in question, not in answers. Answers are only for solutions which resolve problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normall method is to use `SELECT` to check if there are already values in database. If you get zero results then you can add new value.

Something like this (it may need also `cursor`, `fetch()` or `fetchall()`, etc.)

```
results = db.execute("SELECT ...") 

if results: 
    #... code ...

#or 

if len(results) > 0:
    #... code ...
```

---

Probably you may have to do it in with two `SELECT` queries

```
results = db.execute("SELECT ... FROM ... WHERE PName = ... ") 

if results: 
    print("ERROR: PName exists with PCode", results[0])
else:
    results = db.execute("SELECT ... FROM ... WHERE PCode = ... ") 
    if results: 
         print("PCode exists with PName", results[1])
         db.execute("UPDATE ...") 
    else:
         db.execute("INSERT ...")
```

---

**EDIT:**

Minimal working code

```
import sqlite3

# --- functions ---

def drop_db(db):
    db.execute('''DROP TABLE IF EXISTS product''')
    db.commit()

def create_db(db):
    db.execute('''CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS product (
        id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
        PCode INTEGERT,
        PName TEXT
    );''')
    db.commit()

def insert_example_data(db):    
    db.execute("INSERT INTO product (PCode, PName) VALUES (1, 'Phone')")
    db.execute("INSERT INTO product (PCode, PName) VALUES (2, 'Car')")
    db.commit()    

def test(db, code, name):
    print('--- test:', name, code, '---')

    result = db.execute("SELECT * FROM product WHERE PName=?", (name,)).fetchone()

    if result:
        print('ERROR PName exists with PCode:', result[1], 'and ID:', result[0])
    else:
        result = db.execute("SELECT * FROM product WHERE PCode=?", (code,)).fetchone()
        if result:
            print('PCode exists with PName:', result[2], 'and ID:', result[0])
            print('UPDATE PName to:', name)
            db.execute('UPDATE product SET PName=? WHERE Pcode=?', (name, code))
            db.commit()
        else:
            print('INSERT')
            db.execute('INSERT INTO product (PCode, PName) VALUES (?, ?)', (code, name))
            db.commit()

def display(db, code=None, name=None):
    print('--- display', code, name, '---')
    if code is None and name is None:
        print('** need code and/or name **')
        return

    if code is not None and name is None:
        results = db.execute("SELECT * FROM product WHERE PCode=?", (code,))
    if code is None and name is not None:
        results = db.execute("SELECT * FROM product WHERE PName=?", (name,))
    if code is not None and name is not None:
        results = db.execute("SELECT * FROM product WHERE PCode=? AND PName=?", (code, name,))

    for row in results:
        print(row)

# --- main ---

db = sqlite3.Connection("data.sqlite")

drop_db(db)
create_db(db)
insert_example_data(db)

test(db, 3, 'Car')
test(db, 7, 'Boat')
test(db, 7, 'House')

display(db, code=7)
display(db, name='Boat')
display(db, name='House')
display(db)

db.close()
```